# Don't have permissions after a long time

Tags: manager, unprofessional-behavior, iran

I've joined a big company and after about one month still, I don't have any permission in production environments, but in the sibling team with another manager.

A new joiner has all permissions after about one week and knowing this made me very unfulfilling about this new job. I talked to my manager about this problem and he said I will get them but I think he resists about these permissions. Should I change my job (I like this new job but I'm in 2-month temporary contract) so changing jobs should not be hard but It's not my first choice.

I should mention that I have good experience in my responsibilities. How should I talk to my manager and aware him that if it goes this way after 2 months I will not extend my contract?

Comment: Why do you need the permissions? Is it affecting your ability to do the work that's assigned to you? Or is it a status thing? Straight up, I would be reluctant to give anyone permissions on the production server, particularly if they were a temp worker.

Comment: @user1666620 It's a Software production environment job, so I need for example access to servers for better understanding of infrastructure, without this I can't work actually, I'm not temp worker I'm just in a testing period.

Comment: Have you told that to your manager?

Comment: @user1666620 yes and he told it will be OK since last week but nothing changed, I think he resists for this permissions and I don't know why.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be able to access production servers directly and to go rooting around in there, that sounds like massive trouble in the making. What is the goal you are expected to deliver from rooting around there?

Comment: So you don't need all the permissions, you just need the read permissions? Correct? What tasks have been given thus far?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I need access for better understanding of what is the infra structure.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yeah I need read permission for checking configs and structure of infra.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes permissions become a status thing. Your manager may not have realized you actually need the permissions you are requesting, and wants on principle to minimize their spread. If you just need access to a server to study it, make that clear because your manager may be able to get you read access without giving you permission to make changes.

Only request the minimum permissions you need to do your job, and explain for each why you need it. Also, whenever a task is delayed because you lack a permission, include the fact in your status reports on that task.

Do not compare yourself to other workers. There may be a difference in tasks. When I was a very senior developer I needed, and had, far fewer permissions than junior system administrators. Or it may just be that your manager knows more about computer security than the other manager.

Comment: Exactly. Justify your request **Please do not threaten your manager with leaving.**  Managers really do not like that. Nothing good can come of such a threat.  If you decide the job isn't for you, simply move on.

Answer (score 1):

**Everyone here is assuming a functional company with proper access control rules and answering accordingly. That is not guaranteed.**

The other answers are correct on the following points:

1. Permissions granted should not be a proxy for status/rank.
2. Permissions should be granted based on job needs, not seniority.
3. Permissions should be granted minimally, i.e. you should only need read access to understand the production environment.
4. Different teams may have different permission needs. In my job, I don't have production DB access. People on other projects do.

Notice my use of the word "should." The fact that your manager is seemingly willing to give you all permissions (or at least never made the distinction in your discussion between read and write with him) makes me wonder whether any of that matters.

It is difficult for us outsiders to peel apart whether permissions are actually a status thing at this company. A friend worked at a company where anyone the boss trusted was often given the admin password to their computer so they didn't have to call IT. That wasn't planned security, just a sign of favoritism.

In one of my jobs, there were long passwords to make it seem like security was taken seriously, but they were kept in a plaintext file on the Google Drive for anyone to use. People who had their access restricted to that file had been moved from trusted to not trusted.

A person I met at a hackathon had a company where passwords were sent via FB. Whether you got admin rights to the server or not depended on whether the boss thought your personal FB password was secure.

If others on your team who do the same work have the access permissions you are seeking, then it could very well be a trust issue. If not, then it is probably a permissions management issue.

If it is a trust issue, you should probably depart because their threshold to trust seems low if a junior guy gets full permissions in a week.

Comment: The formatting has got confused but an earlier wording was: "in the sibling team with another manager, a new joiner has all permissions after about one week". That could be a matter of the other manager knowing less about computer security than the OP's manager, or the other worker having a different job with different needs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get permissions to access the company's production environment unless you have a need to do so. "Better understanding of the infrastructure" doesn't seem a "need" to me. You say you can't do your job without this. Are there tasks that you couldn't do without access to the production environment? Did you go to your manager and say "Hey, I can't do this task that you wanted me to do because I don't have access to the production environment"?

You may be able to find out *why* your colleague got access after a week, and there may be a good reason for it. I would assume that you won't get access based on how long you are at the company, but on actual need.

Comment: Actually, because I don't have a task related to permissions, but see infrastructure makes me more comfortable to request for a task.